# Ant script to check if remote instance of Jboss is running

Tags: ant, jboss

I have an Ant script which is used to deploy my application on two different machines at a time. With the local machine i do not have a problem, but when it comes to the remote machine, I want to check if Jboss is up or not. If it is up then  I want to shut it down but if it is not then nothing should be done. I tried to do this by keeping the attribute of `<sshexec>` as `failonerror="on"`. This works well when the Jboss is already down and the shutdown command only gives some errors. But the real problem that i faced was when Jboss was running and when the shutdown command was executed, it did not shutdown properly and gave some error. It is in these situations that I want to stop my build script and let the user know that there is something wrong with Jboss on the other machine and it needs to be looked at.

The target code for stopping the remote Jboss is

```
<target name="stopRemoteJboss" description="Stops Remote Instance of Jboss">
        <echo message="Stopping Remote Jboss" />
        <sshexec trust="true" host="${jboss.remote.host}" username="${jboss.remote.username}" password="${jboss.remote.password}" command="${jboss.remote.home}/bin/shutdown.sh -S" port="${jboss.remote.port}"/>
    </target>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a short check, I've found following, maybe you could reuse/or use as an inspiration for your script: http://shrubbery.homeip.net/c/display/W/Starting+JBoss+with+ANT

The relevant part for you seem to be:

```
<java jvm="@{jdkHome}/bin/java"
      classname="org.jboss.Shutdown" fork="true" failonerror="false" resultproperty="shutdown.rc">
    <arg line="-s jnp://@{bindAddr}:@{jnpPort}"/>
    <classpath>
        <pathelement path="@{jbossInstallDir}/bin/shutdown.jar"/>
        <pathelement path="@{jbossInstallDir}/client/jbossall-client.jar"/>
    </classpath>
</java>
<echo>Shutdown rc = ${shutdown.rc}</echo>
<condition property="shutdown.okay">
    <equals arg1="${shutdown.rc}" arg2="0"/>
</condition>
<fail unless="shutdown.okay" message="Unable to shut down JBoss (maybe it hasn't fully started yet?)."/>
<echo>Waiting for @{bindAddr}:@{jnpPort} to stop listening...</echo>
```

Comment: This technique does work, but i have put the Twiddle utility through Ant to use for checking if Jboss is running or not using the command 'twiddle.sh get jboss.system:type=Server Started', which returns Started=true when started and gives an error message when its already down.

Comment: The link should be http://shrubbery.homeip.net/c/display/W/Starting+JBoss+with+ANT

Answer (score 1):

Why not check to see if the remote port is active?

```
<project name="demo" default="check">

    <condition property="server.running" value="running" else="not running">
        <socket server="remoteserver" port="80"/>
    </condition>

    <target name="check" description="Print status message">
        <echo message="Web server status: ${server.running}"/>
    </target>

</project>
```

If your JBoss instance is configured as a reverse proxy you could use the alternative [http condition](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/conditions.html) to check the HTTP response code (which would be 503 "Service unavailable", if the appserver is down)